# npm run build on Vue project populates base_url as undefined

Tags: firebase, vue.js, firebase-hosting, vue-cli, vue-cli-4

I posted my environment details [here on the vue/cli github error pages](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/issues/5281) yesterday. It doesn't look like all of the errors get responded to, so I'm hoping you guys could help me.

**Short version:**
I have a Vue/Firebase project. I'm trying to build it so I can deploy it on Firebase. The project works perfectly when I serve it through the Vue UI. When I run `npm run build`, the /dist/index.html file that gets created has hrefs that all start with "/undefined/...". Obviously, this then doesn't work when I deploy it to Firebase, giving me errors like `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'`

**Suspicious Things:**

1. After deploying to Firebase, it is still able to find my favicon.ico even though it thinks it's at `https://myproject.firebaseapp.com/undefined/favicon.ico`.
2. In my environment info, I have `npmGlobalPackages: @vue/cli: Not Found`. My steps I tried are [in the comment of the above GitHub page](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/issues/5281#issuecomment-600240187), but I couldn't get this to change.
3. In my environment info, it says `Browsers: Edge: 44.18362.449.0`. I don't know if it matters, but I've only been working and testing in Chrome.

**Things I have tried**

4. According to many stackoverflow answers, I can `Try by adding <base href="/" /> into the <head> of your index.html. Hope it will work.`, and `You might have used "./" prefix for Relative path in src attributes of your index.html, Just replace it with "<%= BASE_URL %>" and it will work fine.`. I tried both, and it still doesn't work (I also tried the asker's suggestion of  running `npm install` again). Other than the changes I stated, I have the generated firebase index.html file.
5. According to many other questions, the `Unexpected token '<'` might be a cache issue with Firebase. They said I could try a hard refresh (which I tried) or clearing my cache (which I also tried). I even tried going to an entirely different computer, and I'm still getting the same error. I honestly don't think it's this though because I don't think my dist/index.html file should be having undefined in it, which is before I upload it to Firebase.

**Code:**
vue.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  "transpileDependencies": [
    "vuetify"
  ],
  devServer: {
        proxy: 'https://myredactedprojectname.com/',
    },
  publicPath: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'
    ? '/' + process.env.CI_PROJECT_NAME + '/'
    : '/'
}
```

public/index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
    <base href="/" />
    <link rel="icon" href="<%= BASE_URL %>favicon.ico">
    <title>soa</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@latest/css/materialdesignicons.min.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>
      <strong>We're sorry but soa doesn't work properly without JavaScript enabled. Please enable it to continue.</strong>
    </noscript>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <!-- built files will be auto injected -->
  </body>
</html>
```

dist/index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html lang=en><head><meta charset=utf-8><meta http-equiv=X-UA-Compatible content="IE=edge"><meta name=viewport content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1"><base href=/ ><link rel=icon href="/undefined/favicon.ico"><title>soa</title><link rel=stylesheet href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900"><link rel=stylesheet href=https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@latest/css/materialdesignicons.min.css><link href="/undefined/css/chunk-02393c0e.868814f6.css" rel=prefetch><link href="/undefined/css/chunk-0413c1cf.da33aaeb.css" rel=prefetch><link href="/undefined/css/chunk-05af17cb.0670aa22.css" rel=prefetch><link href="/undefined/css/chunk-05c2d357.0670aa22.css" rel=prefetch><link href="/undefined/css/chunk-05f9ac48.0670aa22.css" rel=prefetch><link href="/undefined/css/chunk-061bbc7c.0670aa22.css" rel=prefetch><link href="/undefined/css/chunk-0c3f6c05.fa43d5a7.css" rel=prefetch><link href="/undefined/css/chunk-0ffc1848.0cf83054.css" rel=prefetch><link href="/undefined/css/chunk-28537b2e.f613719f.css" rel=prefetch><link href="/undefined/css/chunk-2991328e.53d7c3bd.css" rel=prefetch><link href="/undefined/css/chunk-3451d3f0.0cf83054.css" rel=prefetch><link href="/undefined/css/chunk-50451b64.20012414.css" rel=prefetch><link href="/undefined/css/chunk-579e1ea3.36ca82f6.css" rel=prefetch><link href="/undefined/css/chunk-774d451a.bbdf16ed.css" rel=prefetch><link href="/undefined/css/chunk-796d4363.0cf83054.css" rel=prefetch><link href="/undefined/css/chunk-889ba836.0cf83054.css" rel=prefetch><link href="/undefined/css/chunk-8b217ef2.0670aa22.css" rel=prefetch><link href="/undefined/css/chunk-a2794958.469377bf.css" rel=prefetch><link href="/undefined/css/chunk-a808dfec.0670aa22.css" rel=prefetch><link href="/undefined/css/chunk-a97ba050.343c0125.css" rel=prefetch><link href="/undefined/css/chunk-dbbcb6ca.afbf6e2a.css" rel=prefetch><link href="/undefined/js/chunk-02393c0e.1131b09f.js" rel=prefetch><link href="/undefined/js/chunk-0413c1cf.226cb5af.js" rel=prefetch><link href="/undefined/js/chunk-05af17cb.03fb4e75.js" rel=prefetch><link href="/undefined/js/chunk-05c2d357.d226fc27.js" rel=prefetch><link href="/undefined/js/chunk-05f9ac48.bf6105aa.js" rel=prefetch><link href="/undefined/js/chunk-061bbc7c.616f91e0.js" rel=prefetch><link href="/undefined/js/chunk-0c3f6c05.cd0b340b.js" rel=prefetch><link href="/undefined/js/chunk-0ffc1848.fc935ef9.js" rel=prefetch><link href="/undefined/js/chunk-28537b2e.46a32516.js" rel=prefetch><link href="/undefined/js/chunk-2991328e.007c3af2.js" rel=prefetch><link href="/undefined/js/chunk-2d22922a.59463fdb.js" rel=prefetch><link href="/undefined/js/chunk-2d22a109.07601e72.js" rel=prefetch><link href="/undefined/js/chunk-2d22d746.c132ede6.js" rel=prefetch><link href="/undefined/js/chunk-3451d3f0.88a2ff05.js" rel=prefetch><link href="/undefined/js/chunk-3f6524ae.aaee21ad.js" rel=prefetch><link href="/undefined/js/chunk-50451b64.8e065900.js" rel=prefetch><link href="/undefined/js/chunk-579e1ea3.6d02e597.js" rel=prefetch><link href="/undefined/js/chunk-774d451a.ed3b640a.js" rel=prefetch><link href="/undefined/js/chunk-796d4363.0c75e4bf.js" rel=prefetch><link href="/undefined/js/chunk-889ba836.e0cd6e81.js" rel=prefetch><link href="/undefined/js/chunk-8b217ef2.ced2c34f.js" rel=prefetch><link href="/undefined/js/chunk-a0d25322.4e3c26f4.js" rel=prefetch><link href="/undefined/js/chunk-a2794958.e198bb98.js" rel=prefetch><link href="/undefined/js/chunk-a808dfec.07a35948.js" rel=prefetch><link href="/undefined/js/chunk-a97ba050.51a395a6.js" rel=prefetch><link href="/undefined/js/chunk-dbbcb6ca.c0c8846c.js" rel=prefetch><link href="/undefined/css/chunk-vendors.434320c7.css" rel=preload as=style><link href="/undefined/js/app.0215a074.js" rel=preload as=script><link href="/undefined/js/chunk-vendors.6698b677.js" rel=preload as=script><link href="/undefined/css/chunk-vendors.434320c7.css" rel=stylesheet></head><body><noscript><strong>We're sorry but soa doesn't work properly without JavaScript enabled. Please enable it to continue.</strong></noscript><div id=app></div><script src="/undefined/js/chunk-vendors.6698b677.js"></script><script src="/undefined/js/app.0215a074.js"></script></body></html>
```

Answer (score 1):

So, it turns out that my environment variables weren't set, which was why it was coming up as undefined. I just set my public path to '/' instead.

vue.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
  "transpileDependencies": [
    "vuetify"
  ],
  devServer: {
        proxy: 'https://myprojectname.com/',
    },
  publicPath: '/'
}
```